# Intermittently getting 'Cannot close window' on Chrome version 53

Tags: 2013-sp1, chrome

Chrome version: Version 53.0.2785.116 m

Since my browser was updated this morning, I've been intermittently getting the following pop up error:

> Cannot close window
>
> Your browser settings disallow SDL Tridion from closing this window.
> Close this window yourself by pressing CTRL+W or by clicking the Close button right at the top right.
> Consult your browser's Help topics to find out if and how it can allow SDL Tridion to close this window.

Is there a hotfix for this? The workaround is to close the window manually, so it doesn't cause a huge problem, but it would be annoying for the content editors.

Comment: Any specific actions you see this happening on? I didn't notice this behaviour yet on Web 8 and the latest Chrome.

Comment: Generally when I have been hitting 'Save and close' on a component. However, I can't consistently replicate the problem. It just seems to happen every now and again.

Comment: Hi, Any resolution for this? We are getting similar issue in Web 8. This happens in all browser (some different message text though)

Comment: Don't know of this topic is being read by anyone, but this still happens every now and then. This is on sites9, (9.0.0) with both firefox and ie (ie11.1246.17134.0)