# Cannot Close Window Popup Error During Save and Close

Tags: web8.5, chrome

My question is related to this question: [Intermittently getting 'Cannot close window' on Chrome version 53](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15596/intermittently-getting-cannot-close-window-on-chrome-version-53) but happens in Web 8.5.

We are using Chrome version 73.0.3683.86. We have been getting the cannot close window popup error when we are trying to save and close a component. This happens all the time.

My questions are:

1. What causes this issue?
2. Is there a hotfix for this issue?

[image]

Comment: This can happen if you manually copy the url of an edit window of a Component, or any other item for that matter, (the full url including the CME address, query string) and do a Save and Close. Since you opened the tab manually, Tridion is unable to close it for you. Can you verify if this is your case as well?

Comment: Thanks Atila! Yes, this happens when we manually copy the URL of a component.

Comment: In that case I'm copying the comment to an answer :). Please feel free to upvote/accept so the question becomes closed.

Comment: As @AtilaSos said this is the normal behavior when you directly open and save the content by pasting the URL in the new window of the browser. So This is not a chrome issue. In such scenarios you just click save button and close the browser window manually to avoid this message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if you manually copy the url of an edit window of a Component, or any other item for that matter, (the full url including the CME address, query string) and do a Save and Close. Since you opened the tab manually, Tridion is unable to close it for you.

This is normal behavior BTW. So no, there is no hotfix.

Comment: In my case users don't open the edit window of the component by copying the url. I'm sure about that (and experienced it myself too :-) ). So what to do now?

Answer (score 1):

@Sab you suggest it's intermittent but perhaps it's a pattern you haven't yet identified.

As Atila indicates, it's standard browser security to not let a script close a window that a user opened. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close for more details.

Could the 'intermittent' aspect be the difference between a browser instance being opened as a user 'v' as a script perhaps?

There was a 'hack' you could use sometime ago - but even if it works now - it would be considered working around a security bug and would be fixed sooner or later anyway - but just in case (at least for testing):

`window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close();`